# ApnsPHP Push different behavior on several servers with same PEM

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, pem

I am having a hard time tracing an issue and hope someone can help. We have a Joomla Site along with ApnsPHP that is able to send push messages for one app already. We have a second app, using a different PEM. Only the first message is sent out, then there is no answer from the apple push Server and everything hangs until the time out Ends the request.

The same site is running on two other Servers, on Windows and one OS X machine. Both do send out Messages with the same Code/PEM/Tokens successfully. It is the Clients OS X Mac Mini Server which is failing.

This is what I get on the Client machine:

```
Tue, 15 Dec 2015 17:02:55 +0100 ApnsPHP[42117]: INFO: Trying tls://gateway.push.apple.com:2195...
Tue, 15 Dec 2015 17:02:56 +0100 ApnsPHP[42117]: INFO: Connected to tls://gateway.push.apple.com:2195.
Tue, 15 Dec 2015 17:02:56 +0100 ApnsPHP[42117]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue.
Tue, 15 Dec 2015 17:02:56 +0100 ApnsPHP[42117]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: CYD-Badge-1] (1/3): 157 bytes.
```